Freemarker Fallback Not Working with Multiple Template Loaders in Spring Boot
I'm working on a Spring Boot project where I use Freemarker for templating. I have configured multiple TemplateLoaders in Freemarker's configuration to load templates from two different CDN URLs: a baselineUrl and a dynamicUrl. The idea is that if a template is not found in the baselineUrl, it should fall back to the dynamicUrl.
Here is my configuration :
@Slf4j
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties("email")
@Data
public class FtlConfiguration {
  // https://dynamic/bhnpay-static/notification-template/ftl
  private String baselineUrl;
  // https://baseline/bhnpay-static/notification-template/ftl
  private String dynamicUrl;
  private long retentionTimeMillis;

  @Bean("emailConfiguration")
  public freemarker.template.Configuration createFtlConfigBean() throws IOException {
    freemarker.template.Configuration cfg = new freemarker.template.Configuration(
        freemarker.template.Configuration.VERSION_2_3_31);
    cfg.setDefaultEncoding(NotificationConstants.UTF_8);
    cfg.setLogTemplateExceptions(false);
    cfg.setWrapUncheckedExceptions(true);
    cfg.setFallbackOnNullLoopVariable(false);
    cfg.setLocalizedLookup(false);
    List<TemplateLoader> loaders = new ArrayList<>();
    // CloudTemplateLoader is just a wrapper on UrlTemplateLoader
    loaders.add(new CloudTemplateLoader(new URL(baselineUrl)));
    loaders.add(new CloudTemplateLoader(new URL(dynamicUrl)));
    cfg.setTemplateLoader(
        new MultiTemplateLoader(loaders.toArray(new TemplateLoader[0])));
    cfg.setCacheStorage(new MruCacheStorage(5000, Integer.MAX_VALUE));
    cfg.setTemplateUpdateDelayMilliseconds(retentionTimeMillis);
    return cfg;
  }

}

Below is how i am trying to load template :
@Component
@Slf4j
public class FtlTemplateHandler {

    private final Configuration configuration;

    @Autowired
    public FtlTemplateHandler(@Qualifier("emailConfiguration") Configuration configuration) {
        this.configuration = configuration;
    }

    public String getTemplateAsHtml(String emailTemplateUrl) {
        try {
            Template template = configuration.getTemplate(emailTemplateUrl);
            // Process the template
        } catch (IOException e) {
           try {
             log.info("removing template from cache {}", emailTemplateUrl);
             configuration.removeTemplateFromCache(emailTemplateUrl);
             Thread.sleep(10000);
           } catch (IOException | InterruptedException ex) {
             // process exception
           }
       }
    }
}


My cloud template loader :
@Slf4j
public class CloudTemplateLoader extends URLTemplateLoader {
  private URL root;
  public CloudTemplateLoader(URL root) {
    super();
    this.root = root;
  }
  public URL getRoot() {
    return root;
  }
  public void setRoot(URL root) {
    this.root = root;
  }
  @Override
  protected URL getURL(String template) {
    try {
      return new URL(root, template);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
      log.error("Error while loading templates from cloud.");
    }
    return null;
  }
}

Getting below error :
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: https://baseline/bhnpay-static/notification-template/ftl/en-US/b9b09aa4-fd39-4812-924e-1fe7f6d4ed51.ftl
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:2000)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1589)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getHeaderField(HttpURLConnection.java:3256)
    at java.base/java.net.HttpURLConnection.getHeaderFieldDate(HttpURLConnection.java:601)
    at java.base/java.net.URLConnection.getLastModified(URLConnection.java:567)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getLastModified(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:392)
    at freemarker.cache.URLTemplateSource.lastModified(URLTemplateSource.java:94)
    at freemarker.cache.URLTemplateLoader.getLastModified(URLTemplateLoader.java:50)
    at freemarker.cache.MultiTemplateLoader$MultiSource.getLastModified(MultiTemplateLoader.java:142)
    at freemarker.cache.MultiTemplateLoader.getLastModified(MultiTemplateLoader.java:99)
    at freemarker.cache.TemplateCache.getTemplateInternal(TemplateCache.java:439)

but the template is present at the dynamic url, that means after looking at baseline cdn it is not checking the dynamic cdn.
I have verified that the URLs are correct and accessible.
I tried clearing the cache to ensure it's not a caching issue, but the fallback still doesn't work.

You get a 403 not a 404. 403 means a security thing, so you probably need some additional error handling in your CloudTemplateLoader for the 403 (which I suspectyou only have for the 404 or a 503).

Please don't add code as comments that is unreadable, please include the code in the question (ideally the whole class). From what I can decipher here you only return null when a MalformedURLException occurs, everything else will break the template loading.

Sorry, have updated the cloud template loader in question.
You suggesting i need to check for the availability of the template at the url before returning the url.
So that if not found it can return null and fallback can work .

Not sure if you need to do that, but rather override another method (looks like the findTemplateSource from the URLTemplateLoader, in which you call a super method and wrap it in a try/catch to handle certain exceptions and return null. That way the next one will be called instead of the whole resolution process breaking.

We can give more advice if you would include the full stacktrace (which you can get by logging it from the getTemplateAsHtml method with log.error("some message", ex); where ex is the exception). This way you can pinpoint the method you would need to override.

Another option is to use the SpringTemplateLoader instead of your own CloudTemplateLoader and provide a templateLoaderPath (which is basically the root you are using now). The Spring one has some extensive exception handling and checks for existence build in (over various resources), which might help without using a custom build TemplateLoader in the first place.

The HTTP 403 response will certainly give back content (an error page), in which case URLTemplateLoader sees that as success (we got content returned), so there's no need for a fallback. URL-s in itself is a low-level concept to point at a resource, like a local file has an URL, or something on your classpath has an URL. HTTP is a higher level protocol, and even though we do use URL-s as part of it, it's much more than just  URL-s. So URLTemplateLoader won't handle HTTP.

URLTemplateLoader is perfectly capable of handling HTTP and will throw an exception (which is what happens here) if it doesn't get a 200 (OK) at least that is what the underling URLConnection will do instead of returning an InputStream.

Thanks for the response, I have added the stacktrace in the question.

Validating the connection to the url before returning it worked for me actually.
@Override
  protected URL getURL(String template) {
    try {
      URL url = new URL(root, template);

      if (isTemplateAvailable(url)) {
        return url;
      } else {
        log.warn("Template not found or inaccessible at URL: {}", url);
      }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
      log.error("Malformed URL when loading template {}: ", template, e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      log.error("IOException when checking template availability: ", e);
    }

    return null;
  }

  private boolean isTemplateAvailable(URL url) throws IOException {
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
    connection.connect();
    int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
    connection.disconnect();
    return responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK;
  }

